# Mongo merge field aggregation claims input is string

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation and I want to move the selected fields from nested object (in array) to root of the output.

This is the source aggregation:

```
db.user_activity.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "userId": "1e40v0b1j5"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "itemId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "item_doc"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userId: 1,
      date: 1,
      itemId: 1,
      action: 1,
      vote: 1,
      item_doc: 1
    }
  }
])
```

It returns such objects:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5f4ddd8c64d8905be4d2b9a2"),
"action": "vote",
"date": ISODate("2020-09-01T05:35:08.822Z"),
"itemId": "1eh42irfo45m",
"item_doc": [
  {
    "_id": "1eh42irfo45m",
    "comments": {
      "count": 1,
      "last": ISODate("2020-09-01T05:35:08.853Z")
    },
    "info": {
      "caption": "First question",
      "slug": "first-question",
    },
    "type": "poll",
    "votes_count": 1
  }
],
"userId": "1e40v0b1j5",
"vote": "neutral"
},
```

This is how I think after reading the documentation that the merge should look like:

```
db.user_activity.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "userId": "1e40v0b1j5"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "itemId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "item_doc",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "item_doc",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userId: 1,
      date: 1,
      
itemId: 1,
      action: 1,
      vote: 1,
      "info.slug": 1,
      "info.caption": 1,
      comments: 1
    }
  }
])
```

but it fails:

```
query failed: (Location40400) $mergeObjects requires object inputs, but input "item_doc" is of type string
```

I have tried this pipeline first:

```
 $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['item_doc', 0] }, '$$ROOT'] } }
```

Which does not make sense to me. There is an array.

To simplify here is the sandbox to try: https://mongoplayground.net/p/11to4186FPX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$mergeObjects` accept an objects and `item_doc` field is an array it requires to unwind(deconstruct) before merge, second you missed `$` in `item_doc` inside `$mergeObjects`,

**First way**

- you can use `$unwind` and then `$mergeObjects`

```
  { $unwind: "$item_doc" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$item_doc", "$$ROOT"] } } },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nsxbcJI72m6)

**Second way**

- you can use `$arrayElemAt` for index 0 inside `$mergeObjects`

```
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$item_doc", 0] }, "$$ROOT"]
      }
    }
  },
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i87jARWICqI)

Comment: I tried both approaches but I think now that I missed dollar sign.

Comment: Second solution working fine for me . Thanks @turivishal